How can enchantments work to create computers?
The world I’m creating never really gets science the way we have it, instead there’s magic and people study the different schools of it to expand it and see how it can be used to benefit society and over time it creates a lot of analogies for modern day things. Divination starts to be used as therapy, healing and alchemy start to be used as medicine (injury vs illness basically).
The way magic works is very similar to how real life witches describe how real magic works—you have a specific intention and put your energy into that intention. Only these magical effects are like what you’d see in Dungeons and Dragons and not mundane like real life. Everyone has it but it takes years of studying and practice to get to the level of a healer or a diviner, but everyone probably subconsciously uses it to an extent throughout the day.
I want enchantments to create the internet and computers. I think computers would come first and then the internet tbh. But I want them to eventually have phones, cameras, tvs, vehicles (maybe), and video games. Everything is done via enchantments. Machine production is because of an enchantment. etc. It has limitations which is where human labor comes in but the enchantment would streamline the process, and it would be one of the newest magical discoveries because previously enchantments would make like icy arrows or let you walk on water and was mostly a military thing (unless I can think of more general uses but my mind goes blank).
I think the way enchantments work is that the enchanter(s) put their energy into something that can hold it for a really long time. Eventually it needs to be replenished or replaced because the enchantment wears off, but this could take decades with a really good enchantment. Idk what that thing will be but I’ll figure it out.
But I need a basic explanation as to how the “internet” in this world would work. It doesn’t need to be complicated bc quite frankly I don’t know how it works, but I can’t figure out how to make intention and energy work into a way to make a stabilized system that anyone can tap into whenever they want, especially when that would be very energetically exhausting.
Also I’m sorry if I used the tags wrong, I’m new here. I’ll change it if I did.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Magic mirrors or reflections in bowls of water or crystal globes is the staple for long range communication. There's no need for anything else. Basically you're projecting to a prepared medium using magic instead of electricity.
Crystal balls are pretty common even now.
It's wireless even!

I think that could work. They could have “phones”, and then even probably “computers” at some point!


But I need a basic explanation as to how the “internet” in this world would work.

Sympathetic magic
Sympathetic magic can serve as a basis. In brief, this is the belief that objects or people can be manipulated from distance.
For a lot more in-depth examination, see chapter 3 of The Golden Bough: a study of magic and religion by Sir James George Frazer  (free on Project Gutenberg).
This typically encompasses two concepts:
Similarity
Described by the phrase "like produces like".
The sympathetic link achieved via something resembling your target. The most classical example would be a voodoo doll of a person which lets you affect said person.
It also covers other forms of imitation. Like mimicking an action that cascades into another version of the same action. You can sprinkle some water to cause rain to fall elsewhere.
Contagion
Also "contact".
This is the belief that once two things have been close together they share a mystical bond. And you can use one of these to affect the other. Again, classical example might be using hair or blood of a person to affect the person. Or otherwise part of something (chip off a house) to find or affect the thing.
There is no need for the two things sharing a bond to literally have been one in the past, either. Somebody's treasured item will also have a bond with them. Or a possession like clothes, even if not treasured but often (or at least recently) used.
Beyond that
There are more concepts related or similar to sympathy that might sometimes be entangled with it.
Names
A person can also be reached via their name. This can be either similarity or contagion. Or an entirely different an unrelated practice - fiction has played with it in various ways. When the magic starts being based on the name rather than just invoking the name, you get into true name territory.
Magical correspondences
When a tool corresponds with some desired effect. This is a bit like the "similarity" aspect but taken a step beyond and working on symbolism. Crystals, flowers, base materials (like metals), even colours can be used because they symbolise some desired property.
"As above, so below"
On the outer edges of sympathy is this popular phrase taken from hermetic texts. What it aims to express can be boiled down to a link between the microcosm (more or less "the self") and the macrocosm (the universe). And that understanding one can lead to understanding the other. And even manipulate them.
The interpretations of this varies a lot. But often it does symbolise sympathetic magic in some way or another.
How?
Well, let us talk about in broad strokes how the Internet works. Then we can re-work it via sympathy. This is not going to be very detailed because it does not need to be.
The Internet is a an interconnected network of computers. Hence the name. When your computer wants to talk to another computer (for example, because the other computer has a really nice cat picture) then your computer typically knows the name of the other. But not really how to talk to it. The two computers can be in the same room or in two different continents on the world. But what happens is that they do talk to each other via their names.
We can easily represent this process as magic by changing very little in what happens. Mostly changing the means to sympathy rules. Each can be examined individually or combined with others. Working backwards from the smaller ones to the larger

"As above, so below" - a magical device can be mystically linked to the cosmos/heavens. Thus magic devices work with each other by exploiting the rules of heavens. Perhaps different "networks" can also be linked to different constellations or other heavenly bodies (planets, stars, moons).

To make this aspect need replenishment: perhaps the magical device has to be periodically attuned to the macrocosm again. A good enchanter might be able to make it work for a while but eventually gets "out of sync" on a mystical level. Maybe it is because the universe changes but the device does not. At any rate, the connection might need to be re-established or strengthened.


names can still exist. Similar to how current computers use names. Such as 192.168.0.1 or 104.18.43.226 or worldbuilding.stackexchange.com. Magical devices can have arcane names or similar.

To make this aspect need replenishment: devices can have their name changed. Maybe it is just part of the process - even humans do not keep their own name forever. Perhaps the magical devices start to respond to a different version of <arcane squiggle>. Or maybe somebody renames them. Maybe names just do not "stick" to objects as they do to living beings, so a magical device would need to be given a name (even the old one) every once in a while.


magical correspondences - the magical devices incorporate some correspondence tool. That might provide the link. Like a particular flower or crystal or others or multiple at once to attune the device to connect to others.

To make this aspect need replenishment: this should be easy. A lot of the things used for correspondence are quite temporary. Like flowers. But even crystals can maybe be "used up". Think of a battery - even rechargeable ones eventually stop accepting charge - the same might happen with crystals. Or the crystals just need re-alignment. Other correspondence tools might similarly either be "used up" or just physically expire after a while.


contagion - magic devices need to be brought in contact with something and then they exploit this. It could be that they all need a grain of some common thing. For example, all magical devices that have a grain of sand from the same temple can connect together. But if you need to connect to a separate "network" you need a grain of sand from another temple. Or could be the opposite and you need to leave a small piece of your magical device together with pieces of other magical devices and this form the network.

To make this aspect need replenishment: contagion, while strong, typically does not last forever. A drop of blood from a person might be no good when it dries up. Similarly, a piece that participates in a "network" might need to be replaced every once in a while because as time goes on, the link becomes weaker and weaker.


similarity - perhaps similar to "As above, so below" but with more direct relation. The magic devices can mimic a connection and thus be connected. They can use anthills, or bee hives, or maybe even other ecological systems like lakes or seas to imitate "we are together".

To make this aspect need replenishment: similarity is fleeting. Things change and so should their imitation. If the magical device is adorned with images of what it tries to represent, the images might need to be repainted. Or otherwise the likeness adjusted to produce like again.




Student: Why is it that famous wizards always have such annoyingly long true names like Crystalgloboscircame or Viliscaduceusvenalis?  Teacher: They SEO well.

@Nosajimiki Spell Engine Optimisation is important.

I was thinking Scry Engine Optimisation, but that works too.

Time for the joke answer.
Traditional fantasy magic? Like D&D? Just use Animate dead.
Use them as the individual switches in place of the real worlds original vacuum tubes.
Perhaps think Logopolis (Doctor Who) but with animated skeletons doing very small calculations.
You'll need a lot of space for one 'computer' even using animated mouse skeletons, input and output is on little wooden cards with holes punched in them like the original computer cards, later you can use the output card to 'program' clockwork automata to play a tune or flash a semaphore message.. the "internet" is the disk world's clacks (semaphore towers) 

On one hand, that's not much of traditional magic (as in IRL). Zombies and skeletons are mostly bound to fiction. Even the Haitian voodoo zombies which even have books written for them are living people. Real life magicians who manipulate the dead typically commune with ghosts/spirits or attempt to control them. On the other hand necro-computing sounds like a really cool concept to integrate

@VLAZ  consider that on the low end a 486 processor contained around 1.1 million transistors and assuming each animated skeletons in your 'circuit' is performing a binary function of 'on or of' in place of those, and you're using human skeletons, that's a pretty big cities worth of them standing around in little alcoves lining the streets (maybe with an arm in the air or not, passing coloured pebbles or notes on bits of paper back and forth, some shuffling beads back and forth on abaci, perhaps a bunch of integrated clockwork, cogs and gears)..

@VLAZ I'd imagine it as a sort of necro-Borg-cube  .. processing speed is going to be a bit slow, ask a simple question and you might have to wait a few days for an answer.. [ponders] you know something like that might work as an oracle of delphi type thing with adequate handwaving  with text recognition 'software' hard memory storage can be a huge library in cuneiform on clay tablets

Required Spells
Computing technology can be based on combining a few common spells

Read Thoughts - The caster can explore thoughts of a target mind. A caster can think of a subject and the target mind would reveal all the thoughts and knowledge it has on the subject. The mind is aware its being read and what the subject is and stronger minds can resist thinking about the subject

Write Thoughts - The caster injects ideas and thoughts into a mind. Minds can be hardened agasint this

Impart Consciousness - The caster imparts conscienceness to a normally nonliving unconsicnece object. The level of memory and intelligence is based on the casters skill. This is often paired with animating the object, but it doesnt have to be

Teleconjuring - The caster can cast spells at a distance. In order to target yoru spells you need to know the true name of target, all conscience objects have true names


Basic Computer
Witches and wizards have a long history of imparting consciousness and animating common household object. Traditionally these objects would be talked to to give and retrieve information. The power of the spell would dictate how many facts this animated object can remember. A more powerful spell would increase the object's intelligence, allowing it to derive new information from what it already knows. The object would be able to compute simple outcomes of situations, albeit this is limited by the strength of the imparted consciences spell used.
It was also noticed that wizards could avoid the need of talking to their objects by casting read and write thoughts directly. This meant the objects no longer needed to be animated at all. This was generally viewed as a niche usage and its significance wasn't discovered till much later in history
Complex Computer
A breakthough in magical technology was the discovery of creating conscience inanimate objects that could use enchanted talismans. Enchaning talimans with read and write thoughts allowed conscious objects to talk to each other. Wizards would fill a room full of conscience objects which could read and write thoughts of everyone else in the room. The smartest object was crowned as master of the room. A wizard could read and write the thoughts of the room master who would in turn utlize the combined thinking power of the entire room. The ability to calcualte and derive insights were no longer bounded by the intelligence of a single object
Internet
It wasnt until recently it was recognized that the talismans could also be enchanted with Teleconjuring. Now the master of the room could also talk to other room masters across the globe, they just needed to know their true names. Some rooms were dedicated to remembering the true names of all the other rooms and what their area of expertise are.
Even the most inept wizard is able to buy a Teleconjuring Talismans of Read thoughts.  Along with their purchase they are given a few true names of some room masters. The wizard can use their talisman to learn the true names of other rooms and in turn access any information in the vast network of conscience objects. If they have access to write thoughts they can also store their knowledge and thoughts up into the network as well
Practical work
The network isn't just for inanimate conscious objects, animate conscious objects can also be incorporated. This allows the controlling of animated quills for writing, animated tools to producing, animated instruments for music, or to animate anything for anything!
AI driven computing
In the real world it was the increases in computational power that allowed us to create artifical intelligence. Ironically in this world artificial intelligence has allowed them to improve their computational power

Welcome to [worldbuilding.se], @Alex. When you have a moment, please carefully read [tour], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask], and [ask] to better understand the limits of this site, including an invitation to only answer well-asked questions. Thanks.

This is a super cool idea, but seems like a fast-track for a magical robot rebellion. Gotta keep them happy somehow; there's a similar concept in Discworld, and they ain't happy about it, either.

What is a computer, after all?
If in the traiditional sense, computers won't lose their abilities after death, it is just a matter of exploiting them - either as undead zombies (voodoo style), incorporeal ghosts or afterlife spirits you communicate via an ouija board. You give the problem and an algorithm, you receive the results. Diligently, error free, without rest, sleep, smoking breaks, distractions. Combined with an enchantment giving you 1000x speedup on the zombies, you get pretty much impressive computational capabilities. These are a bit bulky computational devices, but ouija boards can pretty much be made pocket sized.
If we go farther, please note that out of

phones, cameras, tvs, vehicles (maybe), and video games

nothing equals nor requires computers and we had these long before computers were commonplace. (Cheap!) computers just made them much  more convenient, smaller, cheaper and reliable.
Video games come close, but first really successful video games were built from TTL logic, not computers (in any sense). And there were very successful games before, even 3D ones. What you need is reliable and precise enough manufacturing and a societal change that frees up free time, both for designers of the machines and the population to enjoy the activities - this came well after the industrial revolution in our timeline.
And low tech ≠ no computers
So, just some ideas how the devices can be replicated with lower tech  magic:

phones

An enchantment that transfers your voice through a metal wire to the other end. The qualitative difference is a(n automated) phone exchange, and an undead zombie can be pretty efficient.

cameras

something to capture a picture on a paper - Terry Pratchett's imps painting the picture are good enough. Or, if you have lens (or camera obscura), an enchantment that permanently burns the exposed picture.

tvs

As a concept, Nipkow disc and a way to replicate light source at a distance is enough. But for something of a reasonable quality to be enjoyable, you need either raster scanning or a matrix of pixels, so the easiest magical way is probably one-to-many crystal ball.

vehicles (maybe)

A thestral pulled cart can be way more reliable than any kind of electrical or internal combustion engine, if you put a fraction of mechanical engineering into the cart. Can be quite autonomous, too.

and video games.

Define video game. With a late 18-century mechanical technology, and a ghost controlling the game logic, the games can be pretty impressive. The main change is societal, if the magic helps cheap manufacturing (duplication spells maybe) and people do not worry about getting their next meal (conjuring food) and have enough free time, you can easily have the video game market.

You could go with Brandon Sanderson's approach with Aon Dor and Forgery where the magic system is literally a programming language making building a computer with it very easy. All you'd have to do is write a 'program' using the magic that, for example, enchants a piece of metal with a keyboard to have a magical illusory screen and Windows 10(In one of his books we do actually see a laptop made using Aon Dor, though we don't see the specifics of its making). For more information on using programs to make computers I recommend looking into emulators like dolphin.

The fundamental unit/device of computing is the logic gate. These are simple devices that we make out of transistors, but in the past were made out of vacuum tubes and prior to that electromechanical relays.
You can make them out of plumbing and water in a pinch. Or in other ways still. If magic were real, I think this is one of the first mechanisms anyone (intelligent) would attempt to wish into existence. These devices give a specific output (1 or 0, on or off, true or false) based on two or more (but usually two) inputs. There is a delay on how quickly the output is provided, and they require a certain amount of energy to activate (less is better, generally).
I was watching that last episode of Witcher just a few months ago thinking to myself "if these people were completely moronic, they'd use that spell to magic up a targeting computer and things would get completely out of hand"
Depending on your magic system, magic-based computing would exceed most or all of the limitations in the real world. An internet wouldn't be far behind, either. Some of the latest language model and diffusion model "AI"s are limited by computing rather than theoretical computer science, they could scale much larger but for Nvidia being incapable of building more performant hardware. Likewise, a magic-based internet might have no significant bandwidth limitations, might be able to provide true privacy/anonymity, etc. An oracular Google search engine's probably a good short story all by itself.
